# Boostrap validation not working with .datepicker() and Scala's value="@field.value.getOrElse("")"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, scala-2.10, bootstrap-datepicker

**Usecase:**

I am using Play 2.1.1, scala 2.10.0 and Boostrap 3+ to work on simple example below.

**1. Display simple Signup Form with Date Field:** For this I have created two Simple file i.e. signup.scala.html and text.scala.html.

***signup.scala.html*** looks like below:

```
@(signupForm: Form[SignUp])

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._
@import views.html.component._
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/datepicker.css")">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
           <div class="panel-body">
           @form(routes.UserController.createUser(), 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data", 'class -> "form-horizontal") {
           <fieldset>
              <!-- Header -->
              <div id="legend">
                <legend>Sign up for Guests</legend>
              </div>
                <!-- DOB -->
                @text(signupForm("dob"),
                label = "Birthday",
                placeholder = "Birthday",
                help = "Please enter you birth date.",

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                     <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                     <button id="cancel" class="btn cancel">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </fieldset>
            }
           </div>
        </div>
        <center><p id="copyright">&copy; 2015 Profile View inc</p>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({ format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}).val();
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***text.scala.html*** looks like below:

```
@(field: Field,label: String = "CHANGEME",placeholder: String = "",help: String = "",date: String = "")

@if(required.isEmpty() && email.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()) {
<div class="form-group @if(field.hasErrors) {has-error}">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">@label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input 
        type="text"
        class="form-control datepicker"
        id="@field.id"
        name="@field.name"
        onkeydown="return false"
        value="@field.value.getOrElse("")"
        placeholder="@placeholder"  
        required /> 
        <span class="help-block">@help</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Everthing works nice like displaying calender etc.

**Problem:**

The Only Problem that I am facing is that I am retrieving this below error
when I try to hit on server using Submit Button.

```
[IllegalStateException: No value]
In F:\PROJECT\WORKSPACE\profile_viewer\app\controllers\UserController.java at line 35.
32  
33  public static Result createUser() {
34      Form<SignUp> boundForm = SIGNUPFORM.bindFromRequest();
35      SignUp signUpObj = boundForm.get();
36      if(boundForm.hasErrors()) {
37          flash(ERROR, Constants.Login.FLASH_FOR_ILLEGAL_VALUES);
38          return badRequest(signup.render(boundForm,
39                              InterestedIn.interestMap,
40                              Visibility.visibilityMap));
```

**On Debugging**

On little debugging, I came to know that, despite the validation of Bootstrap at UI end,When I enter the Date, the "field value" is not getting bind with "input field" and hence the null valued field is passed into my controller, where the Form content isn't assigned anything. Internally it assigns "No value" to validation error List.

Is there any Solution as to how to bind the value field to my "Form", so that it gets bind and return me a value at controller's end.